# JAVA incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to my type

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make changes to my GUI in JavaFX by doing the work on a separate thread and returning the object required. However, after doing the work and task.setOnSucceeded() is triggered I attempt to retrieve the created object and get the error "incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to type VideoScrollPane".

I think this has something to do with raw types as it's within the listener this is happening but after looking around I couldn't find the suggestions I was looking for.

Any light that can be shed would be much appreciated.

```
Task task = new Task<VideoScrollPane>() {
    VideoScrollPane vsp;
    @Override protected VideoScrollPane call() {
        try {
            System.out.print("thread...");

            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            Future<VideoScrollPane> future = executor.submit(new Callable<VideoScrollPane>() {
                @Override public VideoScrollPane call() {
                    return new VideoScrollPane(mediaview, vboxCentre, username, project);
                }
            });

            vsp = future.get();
        } catch(Exception exception) { System.out.println(exception.getMessage()); }

        return vsp;
    }
};
new Thread(task).start();

task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
        System.out.println("complete");

        try {

            //where the problem occurs
            VideoScrollPane v = task.get();     

        } catch(Exception exception) { System.out.println(exception.getMessage()); }
    }
});
```

Comment: When you say "get the error" I assume you mean a compile error rather than a run time error. Have you tried casting it?

Comment: Yes a compile error, apologies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the `task.get()` is returning a value of type `Object`, but you're trying to assign it to v, which is a `VideoScrollPane`. You can prevent the error by doing a cast, like so

```
VideoScrollPane v = (VideoScrollPane)task.get();
```

Be warned, if `task.get()` returns something that isn't a `VideoScrollPane`, you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

If you want to prevent the problem entirely however, consider fixing the declaration of `task`, by including a type for the generic parameter. You could change it to,

```
Task<VideoScrollPane> task = new Task<VideoScrollPane>() {
```

This way, `task.get()` will now return a `VideoScollPane`, and you won't need a cast.

Comment: It's better to correct the declaration of the task than to use an unnecessary downcast. That way you ensure the actual object returned is the correct type.

Comment: @James_D Thanks, I've included a note on that!

Comment: I've corrected the declaration as suggested. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared your `Task` incorrectly. You need

```
Task<VideoScrollPane> task = new Task<VideoScrollPane>() { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

**The return type of your `task.get();` is `Object` and not `VideoScrollPane`**, change it to:

```
VideoScrollPane v = (VideoScrollPane) task.get();
```

Comment: It's not though. The declaration in `Task<V>`, inherited from `FutureTask<V>` is `public V get()`. So it's not the assignment of the return type that's wrong, it's the declaration of the `Task` instance.