# JAVA, Trying to sum up an integer value of "weight" in objects with arraylist

Tags: java

Okay so i am trying to sum up weights of the objects in arraylist together and i've came up to problem with this code. The program gives me error calling "incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Item" im trying to find solutions but can't find anything useful. also yes, the item is returning an int from .getWeight

```
int totalWeight = 0;
if (!(items.isEmpty())){
    for (Item i: items){
        totalWeight += i.getWeight();
    }
    return totalWeight;
}
return 0;
```

let me provide the whole code for further investigation.

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Packet {
    private ArrayList items;

    public Packet(){
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public void addItem(Item item){
        items.add(item);
    }
    public int totalWeight(){
        int totalW = 0;
        if (!(items.isEmpty())){
            for (Item i: items){
                totalW += i.getPaino();
            }
            return totalW;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

edit:: for item class

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private int weight;

    public Item(String name, int weight){
        this.weight = weight;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public int getWeight(){
        return this.weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.name + " (" + this.weight + " kg)";
    }
}
```

Comment: (I love your username) The problem is that your items array is declared as List<Object> most probably.

Comment: And what version of Java are you using? Are you defining `items` like `List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();` ? Or exactly how are you defining `items`?

Comment: What is the type of `items`?

Comment: Please show the code for your `Item`  class and how you declare the `List`

Comment: The provided code is not good enough. Code examples should be [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can we see where is declared, or where comes from `items`?. The thing is doing `Item i : items` values in `items` are expected to be of type `Item` and for the error message they are clearly declared as `Object`

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017233/java-incompatible-types-object-cannot-be-converted-to-my-type

Comment: `private ArrayList items;` add `<>` to arrayList as `ArrayList<Item>`

Comment: @Ruslan if i do that, i get another error calling "illegal start of type"

Comment: Can you share your `Item` class?

Answer (score 3):

Moreover, there is a **good practice to use interface type** when declaring new collection.
For example, your items list should be declared like this:

```
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

The reason is simple - by declaring a collection using an interface type, the code **would be more flexible** as you can change the concrete implementation easily when needed.

What I mean is that you can easily change your **ArrayList** to **LinkedList** for example.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is here `private ArrayList items;` You should use `<>` with arrayList.

```
private ArrayList<Item> items;
```

Without `<>` you have raw type [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

In runtime your `items` will be equal to `ArrayList<Object>`. That's why you get *Object cannot be converted to Item*

Answer (score 2):

In your class Packet, you have to declare items in this way:

```
private ArrayList <Item> items;
```

Currently you are creating object items, now you will be creating list of item objects.

Comment: Thank you, that was actually the reason i was scratching my head red. After editing the code to contain Arraylist<Item> I now actually tried running the code and working on it but it gives me nullPointerException

Comment: @BarackO'Barman In your constructor, you create a different ArrayList with `ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();`. Instead you should do `this.items = new ArrayList<Item>();` to initialize the ArrayList you access in your other method.